# AngularJs 2. Как передать данные с сервера (C# Web Api)?

Tags: c#, angular2, typescript, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

Только начал изучать Ангуляр, но у меня появилась проблема: не получается вернуть с сервера данные.

Вот мой action:

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
    string[] values = { "value1", "value2" };
    return Json(values);
}
```

ts файл:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'file-system',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {
    title: string;
    values: Array<string> = [];

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.title = "File system";
        this.getData();
    }

    getData() {

        this.http.get('api/Values')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(
            data => { this.values = data },
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done')

            );
    }

    generateArray(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => { return obj[key] });
    }
}
```

html, в который связан с компонентом:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div>Hello ASP.NET Core! Greetings from AngularJS 2.</div>

<h3 style="color:#C70039;">    
        <span *ngFor="let stdArray of values"> {{stdArray}} </span>    
</h3>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что данные с сервера не возвращаются?

Comment: @Grundy данные не выводятся. Может я что-то не так делаю

Comment: есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: @Grundy такие: angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4032/angular2/http(…) и angular2-polyfills.js:127 GET http://localhost:4032/angular2/http 404 (Not Found)

Comment: откуда взят пример этого кода? какая версия ангуляра используется? в одном из RC используемые namespace были заменены с `angular2`, на `@angular`

Comment: @Grundy Отсюда взял http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-getting-started-with-angularjs-2/

Comment: пример можно выкинуть - слишком старый. С бета версии была куча изменений. У них даже в RC были breaking changes, когда код с предыдущей версии переставал работать

Comment: @Grundy ясно, спасибо

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49899/discussion-between-grundy-and-viktor-bylbas).

Comment: А на Сервер стучится вообще?.................................